splunk search a log and every time a specific line has been written more than 5 time since last search send a mail
what my alert looks like... 
I want to search a specific log every day every 5th minute. And if a specific word is written more than 5 times i want to recieve an email.
What should my alert look like?
Have not been able to try this alert in splunk since the log has not started logging anything yet but i have a feeling im missing something in the alert :P

What does your alert look like now?

Its at the top of my post... https://i.sstatic.net/oz9a6.png

The image shows the alert settings, but not the alert itself.  Please share the query.

Im not sure i understand what you mean... This is what my search is if that is what you meant  index=* Sign service returned error: An error occured during Sign operation log source="/srv/jboss-server/blv-deploy/JVM200/log/bks-eid/bks-eid.log"

Thanks for sharing the query.  The question says the alert looks for a specific word to appear 5 times.  Which of the 10 words in the search is the specific word?  IME, alerts work best when the search does all of the filtering and the alert simply triggers when the number of results is not zero.

Ok! great advice! But i cannot figure out what word to use... or am i interpreting what you wrote to litteraly. You mean i should use "" or something? Most of the words will return almost daily

The question says "if a specific word is written more than 5 times".  What is that word?

Oh,, well okey i mean a specific sentence is written in the log and i want to look for " Sign operation. Check Sign Service (dssdc_srv) log

Try this search
index=foo source=<<my specific log>> "Sign operation. Check Sign Service (dssdc_srv) log"
| stats count
| where count > 5

Have this trigger an alert if the number of results is not zero.  The alert action should be an email that says the sentence was found more than five times.
